# JQuery event only fires once

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a multi-select dropdownbox using [SlimSelect](https://slimselectjs.com) with horizontal text-scroll in each field. Now everything seemed to work, but the thing is, it only works once (first time clicking on a value). After that, the `mouseover` and `mouseout` seem to just give up. I've already looked through stack but all of these questions have code answers and lack the general explanantion on *"why does it only fire once"*, so that doesn't really help me.

```js
$('.ms-class > option').addClass('scroll-text ellipsis');

new SlimSelect({
  select: '#slim-multi-select',
  allowDeselectOption: true,
  showContent: 'down',
})

$(".ss-option.scroll-text").on({
  mouseover: function() {
    $(this).removeClass("ellipsis");
    var maxscroll = $(this)[0].scrollWidth;
    var speed = maxscroll * 15;
    $(this).animate({
      scrollLeft: maxscroll
    }, speed, "linear");
  },
  mouseout: function() {
    $(this).stop();
    $(this).addClass("ellipsis");
    $(this).animate({
      scrollLeft: 0
    }, 'slow');
  }
});
```

```css
.ms-class {
  width: 200px !important;
}

.ms-class .ss-content {
  z-index: 2;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}

.ms-class .ss-multi-selected .ss-values .ss-value {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  background-color: #884fa1;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option,
.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option-selected {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option.ss-hide,
.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option.ss-hide {
  display: none;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option,
.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option-selected {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 0.9em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

.ss-option:hover {
  background-color: #884fa1 !important;
  color: white;
}

.ms-class .ss-multi-selected .ss-values .ss-disabled,
.ms-class .ss-content .ss-search input {
  font-family: 'Exo 2', 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900 !important;
  color: #444444 !important;
}

.ms-class .ss-multi-selected .ss-values .ss-disabled {
  margin: 0 8px;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option:only-child,
.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option.ss-disabled:only-child {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option:first-child:nth-last-child(2)~.ss-option {
  width: 50% !important;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option:first-child:nth-last-child(3)~.ss-option {
  width: 33% !important;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option.ss-disabled:only-child {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.ms-class .ss-multi-selected {
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  border: solid 1px #e8e8e8 !important;
  min-height: 42px !important;
  line-height: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.ms-class .ss-multi-selected .ss-add {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 3px;
  margin: 14px 12px 0 5px;
}

.ms-class .ss-multi-selected .ss-add .ss-plus,
.ms-class .ss-multi-selected .ss-add .ss-plus:after {
  background: #999;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option:not(.ss-disabled).ss-option-selected {
  background-color: rgba(136, 79, 161, 0.32);
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option:not(.ss-disabled).ss-option-selected:hover {
  color: white !important;
}

.ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slim-select/1.23.0/slimselect.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slim-select/1.23.0/slimselect.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="slim-multi-select" class="ms-class" multiple>
  <option value="value 1">Some long value that doesn't fit here</option>
  <option value="value 2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="value 3">Another real long value that doesn't fit</option>
  <option value="value 4">Value 4</option>
  <option value="value 5">Value 5</option>
</select>
```

I'm not that good with front-end stuff, so I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: Please tell us step by step how to replicate the issue. I do not see any issue

Comment: @mplungjan The issue is that after you click a value from the dropdownbox, and then check the list again, the horizontal scrolling stopped working.

Comment: I do not see any scrolling now.

Comment: @mplungjan Ah just noticed that it's probably due to the width, updated the snippet. So the text won't scroll horizontally anymore (mouseover) after you click one of the fields, that's the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following change in js will work:

```
$(".ss-content").on('mouseover', '.ss-option.scroll-text', function() {
  $(this).removeClass("ellipsis");
  var maxscroll = $(this)[0].scrollWidth;
  var speed = maxscroll * 15;
  $(this).animate({
    scrollLeft: maxscroll
  }, speed, "linear");
});
$(".ss-content").on('mouseout', '.ss-option.scroll-text', function() {
  $(this).stop();
  $(this).addClass("ellipsis");
  $(this).animate({
    scrollLeft: 0
  }, 'slow');
});
```

---

**Reason why your code is not working**

Your code only works until you make a click on any of item. When you click, `slimSlect` removed all the dom and recreates it, which removes your event attached to that DOM as well. Since your DOM and event attached to it gets removed, both `mouseout/over` event did not worked.

**How i Resolved this:**

Look in the code block, `$(".ss-content").on('mouseout', '.ss-option.scroll-text'`. I  have attached the event here `.ss-content` when you `mouserout/over` it will search for class `.ss-option.scroll-text` which will be always present.

If you made selection from parent, your dynamic child dom will always have that event attached to it.

**How @Nowshath Resolved this:**
He added a `beforeOpen and onChange` hook which call the method `ScrollText` to register the event to the dom whenever you try to open or change the value

---

```js
$('.ms-class > option').addClass('scroll-text ellipsis');

new SlimSelect({
  select: '#slim-multi-select',
  allowDeselectOption: true,
  showContent: 'down',
})

$(".ss-content").on('mouseover', '.ss-option.scroll-text', function() {
  $(this).removeClass("ellipsis");
  var maxscroll = $(this)[0].scrollWidth;
  var speed = maxscroll * 15;
  $(this).animate({
    scrollLeft: maxscroll
  }, speed, "linear");
});
$(".ss-content").on('mouseout', '.ss-option.scroll-text', function() {
  $(this).stop();
  $(this).addClass("ellipsis");
  $(this).animate({
    scrollLeft: 0
  }, 'slow');
});
```

```css
.ms-class {
  width: 200px !important;
}

.ms-class .ss-content {
  z-index: 2;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}

.ms-class .ss-multi-selected .ss-values .ss-value {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  background-color: #884fa1;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option,
.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option-selected {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option.ss-hide,
.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option.ss-hide {
  display: none;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option,
.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option-selected {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 0.9em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

.ss-option:hover {
  background-color: #884fa1 !important;
  color: white;
}

.ms-class .ss-multi-selected .ss-values .ss-disabled,
.ms-class .ss-content .ss-search input {
  font-family: 'Exo 2', 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900 !important;
  color: #444444 !important;
}

.ms-class .ss-multi-selected .ss-values .ss-disabled {
  margin: 0 8px;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option:only-child,
.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option.ss-disabled:only-child {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option:first-child:nth-last-child(2)~.ss-option {
  width: 50% !important;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option:first-child:nth-last-child(3)~.ss-option {
  width: 33% !important;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option.ss-disabled:only-child {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.ms-class .ss-multi-selected {
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  border: solid 1px #e8e8e8 !important;
  min-height: 42px !important;
  line-height: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.ms-class .ss-multi-selected .ss-add {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 3px;
  margin: 14px 12px 0 5px;
}

.ms-class .ss-multi-selected .ss-add .ss-plus,
.ms-class .ss-multi-selected .ss-add .ss-plus:after {
  background: #999;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option:not(.ss-disabled).ss-option-selected {
  background-color: rgba(136, 79, 161, 0.32);
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option:not(.ss-disabled).ss-option-selected:hover {
  color: white !important;
}

.ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slim-select/1.23.0/slimselect.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slim-select/1.23.0/slimselect.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="slim-multi-select" class="ms-class" multiple>
  <option value="value 1">Some long value that doesn't fit here</option>
  <option value="value 2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="value 3">Another real long value that doesn't fit</option>
  <option value="value 4">Value 4</option>
  <option value="value 5">Value 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks! I saw that both you and @Nowshath have different answers but both with the result I'm looking for. Could you care to explain on why this works and mine didnt?

Comment: I have added an explanation  @YTZ, I am happy, you have asked for the reason behind it. It will be nice to accept the answer you like.

Comment: Also added info why @Nowshath answer is working, please note it will not work if you search. You have to look for every events that will recreates dom and call that function to work his way.

Answer (score 1):

I think your div is regenerated when the data is changed, So the event binding is not happening properly. I have added that on the open event and Change event.

```js
$('.ms-class > option').addClass('scroll-text ellipsis');

new SlimSelect({
  select: '#slim-multi-select',
  allowDeselectOption: true,
  showContent: 'down',
  beforeOpen: function () { console.log('beforeOpen'); ScrollText(); },
   onChange: function(info){
    console.log(info);
    ScrollText();
  }
})

function ScrollText() {
  $(".ss-option.scroll-text").on({
    mouseover: function() {
      $(this).removeClass("ellipsis");
      var maxscroll = $(this)[0].scrollWidth;
      var speed = maxscroll * 15;
      $(this).animate({
        scrollLeft: maxscroll
      }, speed, "linear");
    },
    mouseout: function() {
      $(this).stop();
      $(this).addClass("ellipsis");
      $(this).animate({
        scrollLeft: 0
      }, 'slow');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.ms-class {
  width: 200px !important;
}

.ms-class .ss-content {
  z-index: 2;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}

.ms-class .ss-multi-selected .ss-values .ss-value {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  background-color: #884fa1;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option,
.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option-selected {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option.ss-hide,
.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option.ss-hide {
  display: none;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option,
.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option-selected {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 0.9em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

.ss-option:hover {
  background-color: #884fa1 !important;
  color: white;
}

.ms-class .ss-multi-selected .ss-values .ss-disabled,
.ms-class .ss-content .ss-search input {
  font-family: 'Exo 2', 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900 !important;
  color: #444444 !important;
}

.ms-class .ss-multi-selected .ss-values .ss-disabled {
  margin: 0 8px;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option:only-child,
.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option.ss-disabled:only-child {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option:first-child:nth-last-child(2)~.ss-option {
  width: 50% !important;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option:first-child:nth-last-child(3)~.ss-option {
  width: 33% !important;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option.ss-disabled:only-child {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.ms-class .ss-multi-selected {
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  border: solid 1px #e8e8e8 !important;
  min-height: 42px !important;
  line-height: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.ms-class .ss-multi-selected .ss-add {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 3px;
  margin: 14px 12px 0 5px;
}

.ms-class .ss-multi-selected .ss-add .ss-plus,
.ms-class .ss-multi-selected .ss-add .ss-plus:after {
  background: #999;
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option:not(.ss-disabled).ss-option-selected {
  background-color: rgba(136, 79, 161, 0.32);
}

.ms-class .ss-content .ss-list .ss-option:not(.ss-disabled).ss-option-selected:hover {
  color: white !important;
}

.ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slim-select/1.23.0/slimselect.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slim-select/1.23.0/slimselect.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="slim-multi-select" class="ms-class" multiple>
  <option value="value 1">Some long value that doesn't fit here</option>
  <option value="value 2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="value 3">Another real long value that doesn't fit</option>
  <option value="value 4">Value 4</option>
  <option value="value 5">Value 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Also thanks! I think I read the documentation a bit too fast and missed those options. Now I'm just conflicted which answer I like more ;S

Comment: It will not work if you search. You have to look for every events that will recreates dom.